# Select all values from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to both mysql and php.

I have two tables which are 'members' and 'points'. Both of them including the column 'username'. I want to select all the values from these two tables where username= $POST[username].

So I wrote this but this is not working.

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$sql = $con->prepare("SELECT *.members, *.points FROM members, points WHERE
 username=?");
        $sql->bind_param("s", $username);
        $sql->execute();
        $result = $sql->get_result();
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

And I tried this :

```
$sql = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM members INNER JOIN points 
ON username.points = username.members WHERE username=?");
        $sql->bind_param("s", $username);
        $sql->execute();
        $result = $sql->get_result();
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

And this:

```
$sql = $con->prepare("SELECT *.points, *.members FROM members INNER JOIN points 
ON username.points = username.members WHERE username=?");
        $sql->bind_param("s", $username);
        $sql->execute();
        $result = $sql->get_result();
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

I can't use UNION because the number of columbs are not equel in these tables.

So, Please help me what is wrong with the code? What is the proper way to select all from multiple tables.

Comment: +1 for using a prepared statement and bind variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alias are meant to be used to specify to which table those column belong, so you need to prepend table name to your columns

```
SELECT * FROM members 
INNER JOIN points 
ON points.username = members.username
WHERE points.username = ?
```

You can otherwise assign an alias to your table while selecting and use them

```
SELECT * FROM members a 
INNER JOIN points b 
ON a.username = b.username 
WHERE a.username = ?
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer it worked well(:. I didn't use alias like in your second suggestion.Is using alias have any advantage other than saving time?

Comment: Actually it's the same, using short alias could save up time in long query though

Answer (score 1):

You were close with this:

```
SELECT *.points, *.members 
FROM members 
INNER JOIN points ON username.points = username.members 
WHERE username=?
```

Try this instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM members 
INNER JOIN points ON members.username = points.username 
WHERE members.username=?
```

Comment: What is `*.points, *.members`? I think it should be the opposite `points.*, members.*`

Comment: @Fabio you are correct, I accidentally had that pasted in from the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

check this 
SELECT * FROM `points`,`members` WHERE `points`.`username`="'.$_POST['username'].'" AND `members`.`username`="'.$_POST['username'].'";
you can check this query it is very simple.

Comment: The OP is already using a prepared statement.  Why take him back to something that is vulnerable to SQL Injection?  Also, this tells the OP to use the ANSI-89 JOIN notation.  The ANSI-92 standard has been around for more than 20 years, so isn't it time that we all start explicitly stating our JOINs?

Comment: It is just a logic that how sql will work it depends on use. ok.